# Pointer problems! (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, pointers

I've got a problem with multiple pointers in an onTouch method. 
All pointers are associated with a boolean value, true if down and false if up. It is very important that if one pointer changes from true to false it will not affect the other boolean values.

The problem I'm having is the when for example pointer 1 and 2 are down and pointer 2 goes up (changes to false), pointer 1 is also in that iteration changed to false. This is because the pointers IDs are changing when the pointer count changes.

Do you have any suggestions of how to fix the problems I am having?

This is the code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int action = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK);
    int pointCount = event.getPointerCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
        int id = event.getPointerId(i);


        if (id < MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINT) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(id));
            xA[id] = (int) event.getX(i);
            yA[id] = (int) event.getY(i);

            if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    || (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                    || (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)) {
                touching[id] = true;
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "i: " + String.valueOf(i));
                Log.e(TAG, "id: " + String.valueOf(id));
                touching[id] = false;
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 5; i2++) {
        if (touching[i2] == false) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Was Here" + String.valueOf(i2));
            xA[i2] = 0;
            yA[i2] = 0;
        }
    }

    x1 = xA[0];
    x2 = xA[1];
    x3 = xA[2];
    x4 = xA[3];

    y1 = yA[0];
    y2 = yA[1];
    y3 = yA[2];
    y4 = yA[3];

return true;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try it with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getActionIndex%28%29 to get action per pointer

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of having an id for something is so that you have a consistent name by which to reference it. If the id is changing with the pointer count, perhaps another system of identification is called for. You could make an array of pointerIDs that gets referenced/updated independently of the pointer count.

Comment: Yeah that was my idea as well, but I'm stuck trying to implement it in the code.