# Get coordinates from multiple fingers (Android)

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pointer problems! (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910223/pointer-problems-android)

I've been searching everywhere for a code that simply obtains one X- and one Y-value for each pointer and perhaps some different boolean variables for each pointer to easily understand what is happening.

I've been working on a code myself, but it doesn't work quite as I want to. It will save four different pair of X- and Y-coordinates, but the problem is that whenever one finger is removed from the screen, all of the pointers (in the boolean touching[]) becomes false for a while. Does anyone know how to make each pointer individual, so that when one finger is removed from the screen only that value in the boolean array will become false?

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int action = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK);
    int pointCount = event.getPointerCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
        int id = event.getPointerId(i);

        if (id < MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINT) {

            xA[id] = (int) event.getX(i);
            yA[id] = (int) event.getY(i);

            if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    || (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                    || (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)) {
                touching[id] = true;
            } else {

                touching[id] = false;
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 5; i2++) {
        if (touching[i2] == false) {

            xA[i2] = 0;
            yA[i2] = 0;
        }
    }

    x1 = xA[0];
    x2 = xA[1];
    x3 = xA[2];
    x4 = xA[3];

    y1 = yA[0];
    y2 = yA[1];
    y3 = yA[2];
    y4 = yA[3];

    return true;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using just one `action` variable and looping over all pointers so they will all be the same. Use `getActionMasked` with `getActionIndex` instead. See [MotionEvent Android dev page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) .

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have any idea of how to implement that in my code? I'm reading on the developer page but I'm having trouble putting it all together =P

Comment: Sorry, not at PC to test exactly, but rather than loop through all pointers, just use getActionIndex for i. Then rather than use action, test getActionMasked for ACTION_POINTER_UP and DOWN. In addtion you may need to clear all on ACTION_UP

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try that! I've been searching for two days for an example code that simply returns coordinates for multiple pointers, but I haven't found any. Should it really be that difficult to come across?